# Why does c++ for each loops accept r-values but std::ranges do not?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

A statement like this compiles without error:

```
for (int i : std::vector<int>({0, 1}))
  std::cout << i;
```

But a statement like this does not:

```
std::vector<int>({0, 1}) |
  std::views::filter([](int i) { return true; });
```

Why are r-values allowed in for each loops but not in std::range pipes? Is there a way I could get something like the second to work, without having to declare a variable?

Comment: Please post the error message the second case creates.

Comment: And the lambda should return a bool, to be a valid predicate.

Comment: I think `std::views::filter` is trying to protect you from creating a view which relies on a destroyed temporary

Comment: This is allowed in C++23.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Can you elaborate what was changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The for-loop works fine because the `vector<int>` (rvalue) is valid while the loop is evaluated.

The second code snippet has 2 issues:

- The predicate must return a `bool`
- the `vector<int>` you are using in the views object is dangling by the time it is evaluated, so the compiler does not accept it.

If instead of a `vector<int>` rvalue, the object cannot dangle (lvalue) or holds references into something else that cannot not dangle, this would work.

For example:

```
auto vec = std::vector<int>({0, 1});
auto vw = vec | std::ranges::views::filter([](int i) { std::cout << i; return true; });
```

Or you can pass an rvalue that has references to a non-dangling `vector<int>` object, like `std::span`:

```
auto vec = std::vector<int>({0, 1});
auto vw = span{vec} | std::ranges::views::filter([](int i) { std::cout << i; return true; })
```

Here, `std::span` is still a rvalue, but the compiler accepts it because the author of `std::span` has created an exception for it.

For a custom type with references into something else (typically views), you can create your own exception by creating a specialization of the template variable `enable_borrowed_range`.

In the case of vector it would look like this (but **don't do this!**):

```
template<> // don't do this
inline constexpr bool ranges::enable_borrowed_range<std::vector<int>> = true;
```

Your code now compiles but it will trigger undefined behavior because the vector is dangling once the view is evaluated.

Answer (score 5):

This works with latest MSVC STL and libstdc++ ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v6rEe9314)), thanks to [P2415R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r2.html).

Prior to P2415R2, `filter_view` always stores the underlying `vector` by reference (via a [`ref_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/ref_view)). It was deemed unwise to store a copy of `vector`. Because a view is supposed to be cheap to copy, cheap to move, and cheap to destroy. Storing a copy of `vector` would have unexpected performance penalty.

And due to lifetime issues, it doesn't make sense to have a reference to rvalue `vector`.

But P2415R2 points out that a view can as well be non-copyable, while still be cheap to move and reasonably cheap to destroy.

So P2415R2 introduced [`owning_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/owning_view), a non-copyable view that stores a copy of a range rvalue, and made standard range adaptors use that view.

The end result is, creating a `filter_view` from a `vector` rvalue works with standard library implementations that implement P2415R2.

Comment: I'm using GCC 11.1.0. I'm guessing this would be in a newer version?

Can you think of any workarounds? Best I've got is to use a singleton but we multi-thread.